# Avoid Depth First Search (DFS) from infinite loop at finding all path of two giving cell

Tags: search, depth-first-search

There's a 2D array that I'm going to find all the path from Begin-cell to Goal-cell(no matter shortest/longest).
and there's DFS solution used over the array(graph) and will explore cells (node's).

### The c# like pseudocode :

```
//setin A and B
setAB(beginNode,goalNode);
//collect info from where we was to explore other sub path 
//first seen:
visited.add(beginNode);
//wholegrid as a matrix and visited for memory
Search(wholeGrid,visited){
    neighborsNodes =getNeighbors(visited.last);
    //check in neighbors condition first
    foreach(node in neighborsNodes ){
        if(visited.contains(node)){continue};
        if(node==goalNode)){
            visited.add(node);
            saveOrShowPath();
            visited.remove(node);
            break;
        }
    }
    //recursive call here
    foreach(node in neighborsNodes ){
        if(visited.contains(node)||node==goalNode){continue;};
        visited.add(node);
        Search(wholeGrid,visited);
        visited.remove(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Rise of Problem:
For any random start/goal node that will fall in a loop !

The initial code was written for graph not for the grid.
How to fix that if the problem is related to this: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search
or please aware me if the solution itself is wrong.
-thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the code was written for a graph. Graph can be expressed as in matrix where each columns/rows are nodes of the graph. A number express a possibility to go from node (row) to node (column). There http://cpsc.ualr.edu/srini/DM/chapters/review5.3.html

Comment: thanks ,my means from "the code was written for graph" is the code was worked for guy(cant find the ques link here) who had a graph that may hadnt a possible "join loop" but for grid evey node has full four neighbors and at least evey 4 cell can made a loop. .

Comment: There is a problem in the pseudo code, in the second loop, it will recurse for all nodes even if you found your goal.

Comment: can you test it for 2x2 grid and every time print expanded cell and put output here? The problem may be implementation related not just with logic.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix He wants to find all paths so he needs to continue search even after he found goalnode.

Comment: theres nothing in output becuase of the line that remove the node is exactly after recursive . in other hand the last node that added to visited list also will be deleted without recurse.for one run the logic works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything needs an end. Simplest recursive:

```
calc(factorial)
{
    if (factorial == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return calc(factorial - 1) * factorial;
}
```